Uninstal TBB, "Threading Building Blocks"
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'TBB'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
cara menghapus keseluruhan dari TBB saya tidak bisa uninstal TBB menggunakan pip karena paket tersebut diinstal menggunakan distutils, bukan melalui pip. Ini bisa menyebabkan masalah karena pip tidak dapat menentukan file-file yang dimiliki oleh paket 'TBB', sehingga penghapusan hanya sebagian.

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Note that this is an English-only site.
